# How can i check the time in Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

How can i check the time in Python and run a command every day at the same time?

```
if datetime.time() == 17.30:
     bot.sendMessage(ChatID, "Message")
```

I found a lot in the Internet, but i didn't found something 
which really helped me. I like to check the hour and the minutes.
Later it should be implimented into a TelegramBot, which should send a Message to a Group every day. So Crontab would not be so nice also a timer.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you are on linux you might be better off using crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably better handled with a cron job, but here's the code

```
import datetime.datetime

now_time = datetime.now()

If now_time.hour == 17 and now_time.minute == 30:

    #do something
```